# CSS fit n elements tight horizontally

Tags: html, css

This question is a bit of a css riddle that may or may not have a simple answer:

I have one div (call it #parentDiv) that is of absolute positioning with width 100%.

Within #parentDiv I want to fit n divs, evenly spaced out within the parent div.

In other words, with one div (call it #childDiv1) within #parentDiv, it should fill the screen with the color of #childDiv1.

With two divs, #childDiv1 and #childDiv2, it should fill the screen with the left side being the color of the first, and the right side being the color of the second div.

The key here is that the css properties for all child divs must be equivalent. The reason for this is that I want to add more child divs with jquery later, and have them automatically cram into the parent div.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want with a `display:table` on the parent and `display:table-cell` on the children. Also setting `table-layout:fixed` will make the cell widths independent of their content.

Markup:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.child {
  display:table-cell;
}
```